# Why is Picker control not displaying items populated to it?

Tags: c#, picker, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a Picker which i have populated with object data from the model. The challenge am facing is that when i tap on the picker to select an item, the list is empty. And also when i specify the ItemsDisplayBinding to one of the model properties. The items are displayed with weird names in the form of app-name.Model for example if app name is cool App, items are displayed as cool-app.Model.ModelName...

What could i be doing wrong? This is my code please.

// xaml file

```
<ContentPage 
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:SoftFashions.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SoftFashions.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ShoppingBagViewModel">

 
    
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,200,*"
          RowSpacing="0"
          ColumnDefinitions="*,*">



        <CollectionView    
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingBagCollection}"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            EmptyView="NO ITEMS ADDED">
                    
       

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Cloth">

                   <!-- controls displaying shoppingBagCollection data-->
                   
                </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>


 
        <Grid            
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Grid.Row="2"
                          Padding="0"
                          Grid.ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
                          Grid.RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*"
                          ColumnSpacing="0"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          Margin="20">
        
                <VerticalStackLayout   
                           Grid.RowSpan="4"
                           Grid.Column="0">


                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="LOCATION" 
                       TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                       Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>


                   <!-- picker to display items from the PickupStations collection-->

  
                <Picker 
                       x:Name="picker"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Title="SELECT LOCATION" 
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding PickupStations}" 
                       ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Location}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
/>



                   <!-- entry to display text depending on selected item from the picker-->

                <Entry x:Name="shippingfeeLabel"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Shippingfee}" 
                       WidthRequest="120"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       Placeholder="$0.00"                     
                       Margin="0,15,0,0"
                       IsReadOnly="True"/>

                <Entry Grid.Row="2"
                       Text="shipping fee"  
                       IsReadOnly="True"
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>


            </VerticalStackLayout>
                             
     
    </Grid>
   
</ContentPage>
```

// view model

```
    /*variables*/


    [ObservableProperty]
    Pickupstations selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Pickupstations> PickupStations { get; } = new();

    ClothService clothService;
  


    //Constructor
    public ShoppingBagViewModel()
    {
      this.clothService = new();

      
    }
 


    // getting pickup stations from the service
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Pickupstations>> DisplayPickupstationsAsync()
    {



        try
        {
            var pickuplists = await clothService.GetPickupstations();

            if (PickupStations.Count > 0)
                PickupStations.Clear();

            foreach (var pickuplist in pickuplists)
            {
                PickupStations.Add(pickuplist);

            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   

        }

        return PickupStations;
    }



}
```

// Model

```
public class Pickupstations
{

   public string Name { get; }
    public string Location { get; }
    public string Shippingfee { get; }

}
```

Ofcourse the service fetches data from the internet from where the viewmodel picks up the data

please help me out with this...Many thanks

Comment: "the list is empty" and "items are displayed with weird names" - which is it?  It can't be both.

Comment: Where are you calling the command to populate your data?

Comment: @Jason It displays weird names after specifying the ItemDisplayBinding as one of the properties from the model. Before specifying that, the picker doesn't show any item

Comment: by default C# will return the name of the object's class when `ToString()` is called if no other behavior has been defined.  That is why you see that "weird name".  That shouldn't be happening based on what you've posted, so either I'm not seeing the problem or it exists elsewhere in your code.  Are you **positive** that `Location` actually contains the data that you think it does?  Have you verified in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly assign the `PickupStations` via the **ClothService** in the ViewModel constructor. I write a `pseudo` ClothService.cs to generate the data source of the picker and extract the key element for your reference below:

**Xaml:**

```
                <Picker
                       x:Name="picker"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Title="SELECT LOCATION"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding PickupStations}"
                       ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Location}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
  public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject 
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        Pickupstations selectedItem;

        public ObservableCollection<Pickupstations> PickupStations { get; } = new();
        public MainViewModel()
        {

            PickupStations = clothService.GetPickstations();

        }
    }
```

**ClothService.cs:**

```
public class clothService 
    {

        public static ObservableCollection<Pickupstations> GetPickstations()
        {
            var locations = new ObservableCollection<Pickupstations>()
            {
                new Pickupstations{Name="Bob", Location="Italy"},

                new Pickupstations{Name="Rock", Location="Greek"},

                new Pickupstations{Name="John", Location="Argetina"},


            };

            return locations;
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
   public class Pickupstations 
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Alexander your solution works fine but after adding static data, but the challenge is am fetching all the data from the internet.